# leaking memory while reading a file to doubly linked list

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

Please consider this code I was tinkering with, it reads a file and loads into a doubly linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
        char * data;
        struct Node *Next;
        struct Node *Prev;
};

struct Doubly_Linked_List{
        struct Node *headNode;
        struct Node *tailNode;
        int LLSize;
};

void InsertAtEnd(struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll, char* data );
void reBalance(struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll);
void PrintLL(struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll);
void append( struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll, char* data);

void PrintLL(struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll){
        struct Node *Node = myll->headNode;
        int i = 0;
        while (Node){
        //printf("Node is likely at %ld\n", Node->data);
                printf("Index: %d has : %s", i, Node->data);
                i++;
                Node = Node->Next;
        }

}

void reBalance(struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll){
        printf("Rebalancing myll\n");
        struct Node *Node = myll->headNode;
        struct Node *LastNode;
        int i = 0;
        while (Node){
                LastNode = Node;
                i++;
                Node = Node->Next;
        }
        myll->LLSize = i;
        myll->tailNode = LastNode;
}


void append( struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll, char* data){
        if (!myll->headNode){
        printf("Inserting at start\n");
                struct Node *NewHeadNode = malloc( sizeof(*NewHeadNode) ) ;
                NewHeadNode->data = malloc( strlen(data) * sizeof(char)  );
                strcpy(NewHeadNode->data, data);
                NewHeadNode->Prev = NULL;
                NewHeadNode->Next = NULL;
                myll->headNode = NewHeadNode;
        } else {
        printf("Inserting at end\n");
                InsertAtEnd(myll, data);
        }
}


void InsertAtEnd(struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll, char* data ){
        //printf("%s was evoked\n", __func__);
        reBalance(myll);
        struct Node *Node = myll->tailNode;
        struct Node *NewTailNode = malloc( sizeof(*NewTailNode) );
        NewTailNode->data = malloc( strlen(data) *sizeof(char) );
        strcpy(NewTailNode->data, data);
        NewTailNode->Next = NULL;
        NewTailNode->Prev = Node;
        Node->Next = NewTailNode;
        reBalance(myll);
}



void FreeMem(struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll){
        //printf("%s was evoked\n", __func__);
        reBalance(myll);
        int i = 0;
        struct Node *Node = myll->headNode;
        while (Node){
        struct Node *NextNode = Node->Next;
                //printf("Freeing Node at Index: %d with data : %s\n", i, Node->data);
        free(Node);
                i++;
                Node = NextNode;
        }
    free(myll);
}

int main(){

    char *filename = "/proc/net/dev";
    struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll = malloc(sizeof(myll));

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    if (!fp){
        printf("Error!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char filetext[400];
    while (fgets(filetext, 400, fp) ){
        append(myll, filetext);
        PrintLL(myll);
        printf("myll->LLSize: %d\n", myll->LLSize);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    FreeMem(myll);
    return 0;
}
```

It works OK, as in, it enumerates and prints the linked list, and this looks like the file it was asked to read.

However, valgrind seems to indicate I have a memory leak:

```
==7755== 77 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==7755==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7755==    by 0x1089FE: append (stack_overflow.c:53)
==7755==    by 0x108BF7: main (stack_overflow.c:108)
==7755== 
==7755== 494 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==7755==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7755==    by 0x108AAF: InsertAtEnd (stack_overflow.c:70)
==7755==    by 0x108A62: append (stack_overflow.c:60)
==7755==    by 0x108BF7: main (stack_overflow.c:108)
==7755== 
==7755== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7755==    definitely lost: 571 bytes in 5 blocks
==7755==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7755==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7755==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7755==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7755==
```

After burning hours into it, it still is leaking - 571 bytes is the best I could leak. I must be doing something I am oblivious to, and would like another set of eyes and tutelage. Thanks!

**Update: 1**

Thanks! I made a few changes based on the responses and suggestions : switched to calloc, and made sure to free up the text data I was reading from the file.

Happy to report valgrind checks passes this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
        char * data;
        struct Node *Next;
        struct Node *Prev;
};

struct Doubly_Linked_List{
        struct Node *headNode;
        struct Node *tailNode;
        int LLSize;
};

void PrintLL(struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll);
void append( struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll, char* data);

void PrintLL(struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll){
        //printf("%s was evoked\n", __func__);
        struct Node *Node = myll->headNode;
        int i = 0;
        while (Node){
        //printf("Node is likely at %ld\n", Node->data);
                printf("Index: %d has : %s", i, Node->data);
                i++;
                Node = Node->Next;
        }
    printf("-----------------------------\n");

}

void Freemem(struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll){
    struct Node *Node = myll->headNode;
    while (Node){
        struct Node *Next = Node->Next;

        free(Node->data);
        free(Node);
        Node = Next;
    }
    free(myll);
}


void append( struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll, char* data){
        if (!myll->LLSize){
        printf("Inserting at start\n");
                struct Node *NewHeadNode = calloc(5, sizeof(*NewHeadNode) ) ;
                NewHeadNode->data = calloc( 1,( strlen(data) +2) );
                strcpy(NewHeadNode->data, data);
                myll->headNode = NewHeadNode;
                myll->tailNode = NewHeadNode;
        myll->LLSize = 1;
        } else {
        //printf("Inserting at end\n");
        struct Node *OldTail =  myll->tailNode;
        struct Node *NewTailNode = calloc(1, sizeof(*NewTailNode) );
        NewTailNode->data = calloc( 1,( strlen(data) +2) );
                strcpy(NewTailNode->data, data);

        // wire the pointers
        OldTail->Next = NewTailNode;
        NewTailNode->Prev = OldTail;
        NewTailNode->Next = NULL;

        // adjust our size
        myll->LLSize++;

        // set new tail node:
                myll->tailNode = NewTailNode;;
        }
}


int main(){

    char *nic = "wlp4s0";
    char *filename = "/proc/net/dev";

    struct Doubly_Linked_List *myll = calloc(10,sizeof(myll));

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    if (!fp){
        Freemem(myll);
        perror("Error!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char filetext[400];
    while (fgets(filetext, 400, fp) ){
        append(myll, filetext);
        PrintLL(myll);
        printf("myll->LLSize: %d\n", myll->LLSize);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    Freemem(myll);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are two things wrong with `malloc( strlen(data) * sizeof(char) )`. First, `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1, so `sizeof(char)` should never appear anywhere in well written code. Second, the amount of memory needed to store a string is `strlen(data) + 1`. That is because a string has one extra byte that is not included in the length. That is the terminating zero byte, also known as the NUL terminator.  That's important since the `strcpy` is writing past end of the allocated memory, which results in undefined behavior. So it should be `malloc(strlen(data) + 1)`

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that every `malloc` needs to have a corresponding `free`. The `append` function calls `malloc` twice for each node, but the `FreeMem` function only seems to have one `free` per node.

Comment: OT:  `printf("Error!\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  When the error indication comes from a C library function, should also output to `stderr`, the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.   The function: `perror()` performs all that correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding first leak.  in function `main()`, in this code block:

```
if (!fp)
{
    printf("Error!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

At this point in the code execution, the call to `malloc()` has already been executed,  So the allocated memory needs to be passed to `free()`

as an alternative, do not call `malloc()` until after the statement:

```
char filetext[400];
```

in function: `append()` there is a check:

```
if (!myll->headNode){
```

however, when called from `main()` the array `myll` has not been initialized to anything.  The chances of the first (uninitialized) field containing all 0x00 is vanishing lee small.

You might try calling `calloc()` rather than the first call to `malloc()` (calloc sets all the allocated memory to all 0x00)   The first result is NO head entry is ever generated with valid data

Things go downhill from there.

Please correct